# This Python code for a Custom Calculator was working now I broke it and I can't figure out where I went wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

I had this working and now I cannot figure out what I did to make it not function the way I intend it to. When the program is called by the pyshell it asks the questions as it is supposed to but when the reply is given this is where it loses it mind. It was working and would call the function I have defined but now it will not do so.

I might just redefine the responses to use numbers instead of strings to make it easier and faster to complete the entries, but at the moment it is not working so there is no point in doing that until I can get it figured out.

The error is in the `run_time()` section, it is not calling the function as it should be, I might be missing something. I want it to call the function when the proper response is given.

I did try:

```
k = (query())
f = function_list[k]
f()
```

This did not worth either, so I am stuck. I appreciate any help.

```
def f_to_c():
    temp = int(input("How warm is it out?"))
    f_or_c = str(input("Is it C or F?"))
    if f_or_c == 'c' or f_or_c == 'C':
        updatedtemp = float(temp * 9 / 5 + 32)
        print (updatedtemp, 'F')
    elif f_or_c == 'f' or f_or_c == 'F':
        updatedtemp = float((temp - 32) * 5 / 9)
        print (updatedtemp, 'C')

def calc_trapezoid_area():
    height = float(Input('What is the height of the trapezoid?'))
    length1 = float(Input('What is the length of the bottom base?'))
    length2 = float(Input('What is the length of the top base?'))
    formula = float((1 / 2 * (length1 + length2)) * height)
    print ("The area of the trapezoid is:", (formula))

def cal_circle():
    pi = float(245850922 / 78256779)
    rad_or_diam = str(input('Diameter or Radius?'))
    width = float(input('What is the %s of your Circle?' % rad_or_diam))
    if rad_or_diam == 'r' or rad_or_diam == 'R':
        print (float(pi * width ** 2))
    elif rad_or_diam == 'd' or rad_or_diam == 'D':
        print (float(pi * width))

def query():
    query = str(input('What would you like to calculate? Degrees, Trapezoids, or Circles?')).lower

function_list = {
    "degrees": f_to_c,
    "trapezoids": calc_trapezoid_area,
    "circles": cal_circle
    }

def run_time():
    try:
        f = function_list[query()]
        f()
    except KeyError:
        print ("You messed up!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        run_time()
        x = str(input('True or False?'))
        if x == 'True':
            break
```

Comment: `I broke it and I can't figure out where I went wrong` <- this is exactly why we use version control

Comment: Didn't see that one, the problem isn't that. It doesn't throw an error because it doesn't even get that far. It did take the input from the run_time and match it to the entry then call the function. Now it doesn't do that, nor does it throw an alarm. So that's why i'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your `query` function:

1. It doesn't `return` anything; and
2. It doesn't *call* `lower`.

Instead, try:

```
def query():
    prompt = 'What would you like to calculate? Degrees, Trapezoids, or Circles?'
    return input(prompt).lower()
```

Note the following:

- `input` already returns a string, no need to call `str()`;
- You need to explicitly `return` the value; and
- Parentheses `()` are required to actually call `lower`, otherwise you return the method itself.

Also, in `f_to_c`, `"flaot" != "float"`.

Finally, you could improve your `run_time` function, minimising the amount of code in the `try` block:

```
try:
    f = function_list[query()]
except KeyError:
    print ("You messed up!")
else:
    f()
```

This prevents a `KeyError` from `f()` being accidentally silenced.

Comment: I totally forgot about that part, thanks a lot. I wasn't even searching for the right things. I really appreciate the help. Now it makes sense why it wasn't working.

Comment: You are not making the most of splitting the program up into functions - if you had tested each separately (e.g. actually *calling* `query` directly) you would have seen these issues.

Comment: I see what you mean, I am using this calculator as practice for some of the more advanced things I am trying to learn. I rewrote the whole thing 3 times trying to find where I went wrong. At first I had my dictionary calling the functions directly and couldn't figure out why, it was because I left the parenthesis on the function in my dictionary thus calling them. Having got so caught up in other problems I created some more, again I appreciate the help.